# iOS 15 Beta 5(19A5318f) runloop run crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsrunloop, nsstream

After iOS 15 Beta 5(19A5318f) distribute,we find a new Crash (only based on Beta 5(19A5318f)) disappear.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000004e12f03a0
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000004e12f03a0
VM Region Info: 0x4e12f03a0 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 9683534753  Bytes before following region: 46687911008
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_NANO              280000000-2a0000000 [512.0M] rw-/rwx SM=COW  
--->  GAP OF 0xd20000000 BYTES
      commpage (reserved)      fc0000000-1000000000 [  1.0G] ---/--- SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Thread 19 name:  MyClassSocketThread

Thread 19 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x199866450 objc_release + 16
1   Foundation                             0x1838a54e0 -[_NSThreadPerformInfo dealloc] + 44
2   Foundation                             0x183a00b7c __NSThreadPerform + 112
3   CoreFoundation                         0x1821d1868 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1821e1824 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 204
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1821241c8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 256
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1821295f8 __CFRunLoopRun + 768
7   CoreFoundation                         0x18213c96c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
8   Foundation                             0x183879d6c -[NSRunLoop+ 97644 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232
9   Foundation                             0x18387a4e0 -[NSRunLoop+ 99552 (NSRunLoop) run] + 88
10  DPScope                                0x1036ecb8c +[MyClassSocket startRunloop] + 51874700 (TNTCPSocket.m:416)
11  Foundation                             0x1838c64ac __NSThread__start__ + 728
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dbec0458 _pthread_start + 116
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dbebeab0 thread_start + 8
```

The (MyClassSocket.m:411) code is:

```
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addPort:[NSPort port] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run]; //411
```

We have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Any success? I am here with the same crash.